# Is it possible to disable specific message in pylint?

Tags: python, python-import, pylint

I'm trying to disable a specific warning `w0611 ("Unused import %s")` using `pylintrc`.

But I don't want to disable all warnings of that type, but only the one: `"Unused import __fixer__"`. I used this import in a way that pylint doesn't understand and I want to keep that import.

```
W:  6, 0: Unused import __fixer__ (unused-import)
```

How can I disable this specific warning in the `pylintrc`. Is it possible?

Comment: That might be easier with a line-specific comment `# pylint: disable=unused-import` than in `pylintrc`. What is `__fixer__`, and why does it appear to be unused?

Comment: I don't want to use a line-specific comment `# pylint: disable=unused-import` because i want it to let me know when i'm doing stuff like that.

Comment: I haven't understood what you meant

Comment: I want pylint to tell me when I'm using unnecessary imports

Comment: Yes, but if you put a comment on *that specific (`import __fixer__`) line*, that is the only line that warning will be suppressed for. See e.g. http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message

Comment: yes, that actually work! you truly helped me!

Comment: But if I wanted to fix it to all my files that use import __fixer__ at the same way as this file. there isn't option to do that in the pylintrc?

Comment: I don't know whether or not you can do it at that level of detail, sorry.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I created answer based on your comments. If someone wants to make their own - please do it and let me know and I will delete my answer.